# mysql I want to manipulate data between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table for production :

```
--------  ---------
| Items | quantity | 
--------  ---------
| A     |   100    |
--------------------
| B     |   30     |
--------------------
| A     |   10     |
--------------------
| C     |   80.    |
--------------------
```

Table sale

```
--------  ---------
| Items | quantity | 
--------  ---------
| A     |   50    |
--------------------
| C     |   30     |
--------------------
```

Required result

```
--------  ---------
| Items | quantity | 
--------  ---------
| A     |   60    |
--------------------
| B    |   30     |
--------------------
| C     |   50     |
--------------------
```

I am trying to do it with outer join but couldn't succeed. Please help me out .
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select p.items, sum(p.quantity) - coalesce(max(total_quantity), 0)
from production p
left join 
(
    select items, sum(quantity) as total_quantity
    from sale
    group by items
) s on s.items = p.items
group by p.items
```

Comment: Thanks , but I am getting null in case if no entry in sale table like Item- B

Comment: Its not working in MSSQL: "Column 's.Total_Quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Updated the answer. I used `max()` as one possible aggregate function

Answer (score 2):

```
select p.Items, SUM(IFNULL(p.quantity,0))-SUM(IFNULL(s.quantity,0)) 
FROM production p 
left join sale s 
on p.items = s.items 
group by p.items
```

edit to protect against nulls.  You tagged two different SQL databases mysql and sql-server for MySQL i believe it is IFNULL (as shown in code) and in sql-server it is ISNULL

Comment: Just need to wrap s.quantity is coalesce/isnull for when there are no sales.

Comment: That returns wrong sums if sales has more than one record for an item

Comment: @juergen, I may be wrong but I believe it sums them all (even for multiple records) because of the group by statement.